# Kohana - Facebook app URL

Tags: kohana, facebook

I'm developing my first facebook app on kohana 2.3.x at the moment and I noticed that a usual app url should look like this:
http://apps.facebook.com/{my_app}/{controller}/{method}

But in my app it shows the real url.
http://mydomain.com/{controller}/{method}

Any idea how to fix that in Kohana?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this in `application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['site_domain'] = 'apps.facebook.com/my_app/';
```

Comment: hmmm somehow that doesn't work correctly. first off it doesn't load css/image files like then and it appears that it open an iframe within an iframe...